# Ruby Rake object call syntax

Tags: ruby, object, rake

In the case of a call like

```
Rake::Task['somenamespace::sometask'].invoke
```

What is the ['somenamespace::sometask'] that is passed into Rake::Task, I don't understand this syntax, shouldn't I would expect it to be something like

```
Rake::Task('somenamespace::sometask').invoke
```

What is the significance of the brackets here and why are they used?

Answer (score 0):

```
foo[bar]
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
foo.[](bar)
```

It's just a method call to a method named `[]`, nothing more.

I am quite surprised that you haven't seen this method before; it is one of the most important methods in Ruby, e.g.:

```
ary = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]

ary[3]
#=> 16

hsh = { 'one' => 'uno', 'two' => 'dos', 'three' => 'tres' }

hsh['two']
#=> 'dos'
```